# Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\ConfigurationController::show()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I get missing argument 1 error when I try accessing a page. This is my code.

Part of the view:

```
@foreach($stations as $station)
    <span> {{ $stations->station }} </span>
@endforeach
```

Controller:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $stations = DB::table('stations')->pluck('station');
    return view('configuration.configuration', $stations);
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('configuration/', 'ConfigurationController@show');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `$id` from your `show` function declaration:

```
public function show() {
    $stations = DB::table('stations')->pluck('station');
    return view('configuration.configuration', $stations);
}
```

Comment: additional question now I get undefined variable stations and I don't know why

Comment: I think you should post this as a new question, because it's another question (and I will answer if I can)